# Cache the results from the ajax calls to prevent running them multiple times

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, caching

In my project i have a php file that launch a js function that make an ajax call.
My problem is, if a user refresh php page on browser function re-make ajax call and so on.
I need to cache the first result of ajax execution so that if the refresh is done being used data in the cache and not the ajax call is made again.

My call is

```
if (xmlHttp)
    {
    // try to connect to the server
    try
    {
      xmlHttp.open("GET", "top10.php?P1="+oStxt, true);
      xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleRequestStateChange10;
      xmlHttp.send(null);
    }
        // display the error in case of failure
        catch (e)
    {
        alert("Can't connect to server:\n" + e.toString());
    }
```

How can i prevent multiple ajax call from browser page refresh?

Thanks in advance

Comment: But if the page is reloaded, the state is lost, and the only way to store the data is serverside or clientside in local storage or cookies, are there are limits on what you can store clientside (and pretty small limits in cookies), so why not just get the data from the server instead ?

Comment: It would be far easier to just request the data again. If you're worried about it overwhelming the server, you should be able to implement some form of caching serverside if it isn't already implemented into the db system you are using.

Comment: Hy my db system is mysql, how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following flow:

- Before making the request hash your request URL (MD5?)
- Check to see if your *localStorage* (or similar) has a value for this hash
- If no value

  - do your request
  - save returned data in localStorage with hash as key
  - render page
- If value

  - load from localStorage
  - render page

Easy!